# Fluent Nhibernate sublass mapping HasMany with where clause with column from Parent Class

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, where-clause, has-many

I have three entity classes: Entity, Special and Regular with hierarchy as below

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class Special : Entity
{
    public IEnumerable<Regular> Regulars { get; set; }
}

public class Regular : Entity
{

}
```

To map this entities I use ClassMap and SubclassMap
In my subclass I try to map collection Regulars from entity Special with Where clause as following:

```
public class SpecialMap : SubclassMap<Special>
{
    public SpecialMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Regulars).Where("IsDeleted = 0");
    }
}
```

but it not works because when I try to use this collection the error **Invalid column name 'IsDeleted'** is show. It seems that nhibernate tries to find IsDeleted column in table Regular, but there is no columns with such, in table Entity only. What can I do with that?

PS. Probably I've explained not correct, it's my English level:) 
here is an identical to my issue [NHibernate explicit fluent column mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903988/nhibernate-explicit-fluent-column-mapping) but without useful answers

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RegularMap : SubclassMap<Regular>
{
    public RegularMap()
    {
        Table("Regular")
        References(x => x.Special,"SpecialID");
    }
}

public class SpecialMap : SubclassMap<Special>
{
    public SpecialMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Regulars).KeyColumn("SpecialID").Where("IsDeleted = 0");
    }
}
```